# Python Pandas lookup and replace df1 value from df2

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes

`df`  `df2`

`df` column `FOUR` matches with `df2` column `LOOKUP COL`

I need to match `df` column `FOUR` with `df2` column `LOOKUP COL` and replace `df` column `FOUR` with the corresponding values from `df2` column `RETURN THIS`

The resulting dataframe could overwrite `df` but I have it listed as `result` below.

NOTE: THE INDEX DOES NOT MATCH ON EACH OF THE DATAFRAMES

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
              ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
              ['j', 'k', 'l', 'm'],
              ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w']])

df.columns = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR']

      ONE  TWO THREE FOUR
   0    a   b   c   d
   1    e   f   g   h
   2    j   k   l   m
   3    x   y   z   w 

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b', 'd', '1'], 
              ['e', 'f', 'h', '2'],
              ['j', 'k', 'm', '3'],
              ['x', 'y', 'w', '4']])

df2.columns = ['X1', 'Y2', 'LOOKUP COL', 'RETURN THIS']

    X1  Y2  LOOKUP COL  RETURN THIS
 0  a   b      d              1
 1  e   f      h              2
 2  j   k      m              3
 3  x   y      w              4
```

RESULTING DF

```
   ONE  TWO THREE  FOUR
0   a   b     c     1
1   e   f     g     2
2   j   k     l     3
3   x   y     z     4
```

Comment: Please don't post images. (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2285236)

Comment: updated... was not aware of this rule

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Series.map. You'll need to create a dictionary or a Series to use in map. A Series makes more sense here but the index should be `LOOKUP COL`:

```
df['FOUR'] = df['FOUR'].map(df2.set_index('LOOKUP COL')['RETURN THIS'])

df
Out: 
  ONE TWO THREE FOUR
0   a   b     c    1
1   e   f     g    2
2   j   k     l    3
3   x   y     z    4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Four']=[df2[df2['LOOKUP COL']==i]['RETURN THIS'] for i in df['Four']]
```

Should be something like sufficient to do the trick? There's probably a more pandas native way to do it.

Basically, list comprehension - We generate a new array of `df2['RETURN THIS']` values based on using the lookup column as we iterate over the `i in df['Four']` list.